# display a content on footer after hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for the bad title. 
I want to make a text in footer that says "info" and when user hover over it it should display a some text and links to "about us", "returns", "size chart" and so on. 
It should be exactly like the footer on this website https://www.lazyoaf.com/

```
so this is how the footer looks before user hover over it
```

[image]

```
and this is how it looks when user hover over it
```

[image]

This is what i have tried so far

```
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #E0D0C3;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #E0D0C3;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #E0D0C3}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #E0D0C3;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Info</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

but this shows the content when hover over bellow the "info" text on the footer
I need it display content above the "info" text and to be wider

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help.

Comment: Hello @FluffyKitten I have edited my post.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I hope this will help you**

```js
$(".footerbox").on("mouseenter", function(){
  $(this).find(".popbox").fadeIn("slow")
})


$(".footerbox").on("mouseleave", function(){
  $(this).find(".popbox").fadeOut("slow")
})
```

```css
.sticky-footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.contents {
  height: 43px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
   
.footerleft {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: right;
}
.footerleft .label{
  padding: 20px;
}

.footerright {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.footerbox .label{
  color: white;
}


.popbox {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 43px;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sticky-footer">
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="footerbox footerleft">
      <span class="label">Lazy Oaf</span>
      <div class="popbox" style="display: none;">
        <div class="popbox-inner">
          <h4>Welcome to Lazy Oaf</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footerbox footerright">
      <span class="label">Info</span>
      <div class="popbox" style="display: none;">
        <div class="popbox-inner">
          <h4>Info</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- contents -->
</div>
```

Comment: There is a small problem here. 
Its sticky! It doesn't just appear on the footer, so when ever i scroll up or down its there
please see the image here https://imgur.com/a/f4P22
How can i make it stick on footer?